# working with arrays in trino / presto (remove, sort)

Tags: sql, presto, trino

in trino or presto I want to

take an array remove a pattern type e.g. remove "b",
re-order sort the array,
then create a hash from the array.

I know how to get length:
select json_array_length('["b", "a", "b", "c"]');
but I'm unsure how to do the rest

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variety of functions to operate on arrays of values: [`filter`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=filter#filter), [`array_sort`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=array_sort#array_sort), etc:

```sql
SELECT xxhash64(cast(json_format(cast(array_sort(filter(data, v -> v <> 'b')) as json)) as varbinary))
FROM (VALUES array['b', 'a', 'c', 'c']) AS t(data);
```

Since there's no way to directly compute a hash of an array of values (e.g., via `xxhash64`, which requires a `varbinary` value), you have to first convert the filtered/sorted array into a `varbinary`. This can be easily done by first turning it into JSON which has a textual representation and can easily be cast to `varbinary`:

```
xxhash64(
  cast(
    json_format(
      cast(<array value> as json) 
    as varbinary))
```

Comment: Thanks one more question is there a way to convert the '["b", "a", "b", "c"]' to the array somehow?

Answer (score 0):

with the help from Martin here is what I came up with

```
    select xxhash64(cast(json_format(cast(array_sort(filter(CAST(JSON '["b", "a", "b", "c"]' AS ARRAY(varchar)), v -> v <> 'b')) as json)) as varbinary));
```